# What is the best option to create a dynamic board game on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-gridview, android-architecture

I want to develop a dynamic matching game for Android. I want the change the board size from 4x4 up to 8x8 (eg. 7x4 and 5x4 would be valid sizes), depending on the level of difficulty chosen. This means I can have a 5x4, 7x4 board, and so on.

I also want to handle orientation change in this game. This means I want to change the board dimensions in the orientation changes (eg. a portrait 5 x 4 can became a 4 x 5 landscape).

I came up with two different approaches.

1. Create #N different layout files using `Constraint Layout`. Then I put some logic in my `fragment` to decide which layout file to pick up. This would handle almost all the complexity of making it dynamic once the constraint layouts will shrink and stretch automatically. 
   The downsides I realized: 
   a. code will look messy. I would have to `findViewById` depending on the layout chosen;
   b. configuration change might be an issue, once I'd have to change the layout file on the fly;
   c. maintenance would be hard. Imagine maintaining all these XML files.
2. Use GridView. I can make it all dynamic. The Adapter binds it for me, I just need to tell the GridView how many columns I want.
   Downsides:
   a. I need to come up with magic math to make it fit;
   b. height is an issue and `onBind` might mess me up is the ViewHolder decides to rebind the views.

At this point, I'm inclined to go for the first option. But I'm worried about making a decision I'd regret after.

Any advice or suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: To begin with, it's usually a bad idea to make games with the Android SDK. I suggest you use a dedicated game engine/framework, like libGDX if you already know Java. Then it won't even be a problem anymore, you'll just have to draw the grid to the dimensions you want. If you still decide against it, it makes no sense to create a layout for each size because you'll end up needing 32 layouts. So go for dynamic, maybe with RecyclerView even.

Comment: Use Android native is a requirement in my scenario.

Comment: I would use custom a (possibly custom) View for the game tile and a custom ViewGroup for the board that lays out however many of the tiles you need at whatever size is provided to it. Then you can use your gameboard in layouts but can provide easy-to-use getters for tile positions and animate moving stuff around on the board easily, etc.

Comment: That is the point, I want an even board and the board to fit the layout container. Constraint layout would be perfect, but to have dynamic sizes I would have to create multiple layouts, as I would not be able to make it on the fly...